# Rails Devise model won't use custom model controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, controller, overriding

In a Rails (version 4.0.2) have a simple model I generated with the Devise gem (version 3.0.4) called User. I want to customize the controller. So I made a file "user_controller":

```
class UserController < Devise::SessionsController

def create
    super
    puts "this works"

end

end
```

Here are my routes:

```
SecretApp::Application.routes.draw do

root  'static_pages#home'
match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
match '/profile', :to => "profile#show",       via:'get'

devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations", :sessions => "user"}

end
```

I'm assuming when overriding a Devise controller, you have to call `super` in each method unless you are completely overriding the method, correct? In any case, when I create a new User, the console never prints "this works", so I'm pretty sure the controller is not being used. Why?

I did however manage to override my registrations controller for the User model, which confuses me because I'm using the same method to override the User controller (besides the inherited super class and the controller name). I'm sure of this because I have `puts "this is ok"` in the the `new` method and it does print that to the console.

Comment: `Devise::SessionsController` handles sessions (sign in/sign out, etc), but you're talking about creating users, which would be handled by `Devise::Registrations`. You also say you've successfully overridden the registrations controller. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: I'm asking how to make a custom controller class for a Devise model. Long story short, upon registration I have a nested form for the User and a `Profile` model (each user has one `Profile`). Devise is not saving the profile attributes into the profile model. So I need to assign them upon the User creation, hence the User custom controller. According to [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) `Devise::SessionsController` is the proper super class for a custom controller.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood their example, which deals with session management. If you want to handle user creation, use `class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Zach. A controller that inherits from `Devise::SessionsController` should definitely not be called `UserController`. At most, that controller should be inheriting from `Devise::RegistrationsController`. Also, Rails' conventions dictate that you name your controller in the plural form, `UsersController`. Regardless, this is why your code is not working:

When you call `super`, the `create` action inside [`Devise::SessionsController`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/60b6a807649b5deb9e832a53e8cbe2a0edb2f0cc/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L14-L20) is reached. Notice how, in the last line of that action, the [respond_with](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) method is called. This method is the one responsible for rendering a template, generating a response. Once this line is reached, your code will not run.

You have thus 2 options:

1. Call your custom code before you call `super`:

   ```
   def create
     puts "this works"
     super
   end
   ```
2. Or take advantage of the fact that Devise's `create` action has this line:

   ```
   yield resource if block_given?
   ```

   You can then call your custom code like this:

   ```
   def create
     super do |resource|
       puts "this works"
     end
   end
   ```

   This is all mentioned in [Devise's readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers).

In the second option, Devise is using two awesome Ruby features: blocks, and yielding. You can learn more about blocks and yield with [RubyMonk](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent), I highly recommend it!

Comment: This might be counter-intuitive, but in this case Rails **will** execute anything you include after `super`, as long as the method is reached (it lets you do stuff after the render or redirect). [Here](https://howilearnedrails.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/how-to-override-and-customize-the-devise-controller-in-rails/) is an example.